# How do i choose collection with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

How do i select which collection i want to access with mongoose? I have only used the normal mongo db before. Before i just did mongo.collection.something()

But on mongoose that don't work.
I have tried to look at theirs docs but it not clear how to choose the collection, i have also tried to do mongoose.collection, but that don't work either.
It should be simply to just choose what collection you want to use.

Anyone that can tell me how i access the collection of the database?

Answer (score 1):

From the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling), when you create your model:

The **first argument** is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural, lowercased version of your model name.

Therefore, when creating a model like below, the collection will be called `animals`:

```js
var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention schema before you perform any operation on collection using mongoose.
Create schema as below:

```
// define a schema
var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });
var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
```

After this you can perform query operations as mentioned here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#query-helpers
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

To save or update follow save method from above mentioned document.

**Make sure you follow same version as current mongoose version is 5.7.2**